# Getting available opengl extensions on a core profile on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

So while testing my code on an iMac, I stumbled across these questions.
I am using SDL to initialize the OpenGL context. If I specify that I want a core profile with SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE ); then I get an OpenGL 4.1 profile. If I omit the core profile mask, it gives me a 2.1 profile.
Why?

Also, like the spec says, on a core profile glGetString ( GL_EXTENSIONS ) is deprecated. So, I tried going with the glGetStringi way, but alas, GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS is not defined. If I try glGetStringi ( GL_EXTENSION, 0 ) I get an invalid pointer.

What is the correct way of getting extensions then? This works on other OS's.

Thanks

Comment: "*GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS is not defined*" That sounds like you're not using headers that support OpenGL 3.0 or higher. Use a proper OpenGL Loading Library.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong. I double checked that `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS` is defined in `OpenGL/gl3.h`.

Comment: gl3.h ? I've been adding gl.h and glext.h, only. Maybe that is the thing... I'll try it tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Also, for whoever downvoted the question... Your downvote is as helpful as being arrested for no good reason. Thanks for nothing. At least DO bother to explain what is wrong with my question, so i can improve it, and others in the future. I really don't understand what's with just downvoting and letting people take wild guesses as to why. It makes people who ask questions feel depreciated, and without a chance to improve. It is not at all helpful this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reto, your answer was correct. I did not know that Apple included a separate header, and after including that one, it finally works.

If you want to create an answer with that, i'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Thanks.